# I don't understand these codes

Tags: android, stringbuffer

I'm making an android app for my final project at school. 
I only know basic Java and I need to make my app connect to my mysql database.

So I followed this tutorial here with the get method:

https://www.tutorialspoint.com/android/android_php_mysql.htm

Aside from the php part and how it connects and execute the code what I don't understand is this line

```
StringBuffer sb = new StringBuffer("");
String line="";

while ((line = in.readLine()) != null) {
    sb.append(line);
    break;
}

in.close();
return sb.toString();
```

I tried to read this:

https://developer.android.com/reference/java/lang/StringBuffer.html

But I suck at English and reading that won't make me understand what StringBuffer do a bit. I only know that it returns something and it is converted to string type so I think it is the php result.

What I want to know is what does StringBuffer do in the tutorial above? Like they return the value of the php result or not?

And if they do can I use it like this? Because I tried to do like this but got a catch (Exception e) with e.getMessage is null

```
TextView text2 = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.textView);
text2.setText(sb.toString());
```

If they do not, how can I set the result of the php value to my textview?

Comment: Since you are reading each line at a time from the input stream and adding it to a `String`, it is faster to use `StringBuffer`.

Answer (score 0):

StringBuffer is a way of building a String piece by piece. It is an alternate to manually concatenating strings like this:

```
String string3 = string0 + string1 + string2;
```

You would instead do.

```
stringBuffer.append(string0)
    .append(string1)
    .append(string2);
```

Therefore, all it is doing is taking the Strings from **in** line-by-line and combining it into one String.

Answer (score 0):

Well mate, it depends what result you are expecting you can connect to database for example to send or get some data, and then you need a php file as well.
But the easiest way to connect to db is to use [Volley](https://developer.android.com/training/volley/index.html) or [AsyncTask](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/os/AsyncTask.html).
Analise these sample code, it is fully working (but you need a php file which connects with your request:

```
private class YourTask extends AsyncTask<Void, Void, String> {

    @Override
    protected String doInBackground(Void... voids) {
        String strUrl = "http://YOUR_PLACE_ON_A_SERVER_WHERE_THE_PHP_FILE_IS.php";
        URL url = null;
        StringBuffer sb = new StringBuffer();

        try {
            url = new URL(strUrl);
            HttpURLConnection connection = (HttpURLConnection) url.openConnection();
            connection.connect();
            InputStream iStream = connection.getInputStream();
            BufferedReader reader = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(iStream));
            String line = "";

            while ((line = reader.readLine()) != null) {
                sb.append(line);
            }

            reader.close();
            iStream.close();
        } catch (MalformedURLException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        } catch (IOException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }

        return sb.toString();
    }
//Here you can manage things you want to execute
}
```